# unable to utilize tensorflow model under uwsgi + nginx deployment

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, uwsgi

I'm trying to deploy a face detection service using [MTCNN in tensorflow](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/) + flask + uWSGI. I based my deployment on [this docker](https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker) and added this custom `uwsgi.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
module = main
callable = app
enable-threads = true
cheaper = 2
processes = 16
threads = 16
http-timeout = 60
```

but when I try to do face detection using this docker image I just built, I always get `504 Gateway Time-out`. Actually when I dug deeper, I noticed that the code runs fine to [this session.run line](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/blob/096ed770f163957c1e56efa7feeb194773920f6e/src/align/detect_face.py#L92):

```
    for op_name in data_dict:
        with tf.variable_scope(op_name, reuse=True):
            for param_name, data in iteritems(data_dict[op_name]):
                try:
                    var = tf.get_variable(param_name)
                    session.run(var.assign(data))
                except ValueError:
                    if not ignore_missing:
                        raise
```

At first, I thought it was a problem related to threading under uwsgi worker, so I added increased number of processes and threads but without any success.

When I run the same code with flask debugger, it runs just fine and processes the image in less than a second. So it is not a problem with code but a problem with config or combination of these tools.

Comment: This is a problem with uwsgi spinning up multiple worker threads. Your model and session are initialized in one place, but the application (uwsgi worker) executes the prediction code in a different thread. I'm dealing with the same issue and still trying to find a viable solution.

Comment: @BrandonSchabell I ended up using flask + gunicorn.

Answer (score 4):

You also need to set `cheaper = 0`.
This is my uwsgi and it is working.

```
[uwsgi]
module = main
callable = app
master = false 
processes = 1
cheaper = 0
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why this works? What is the `cheaper` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Use `master = false` and `processes = 1` for uwsgi config. There is a known issue that [tensorflow hangs in a multiprocess setting](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5448).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. service was fine without Tensorflow and Keras but as soon as I was Import this libraries, I get an Internal server error.

Somebody told me try [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) instead of uWSGI and that's work.

By the way, You do not need to change much, just

1. `/etc/systemd/system/myproject.service`
2. `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Use [this paper on Digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-7).

Hope to be useful. Also sorry about my English